# Docker linux versions

Tags: docker

I am learning docker basics. I created a simple image

```
FROM alpine
RUN apk add --update redis
CMD ["redis-server"]
```

I started the container and logged in using

```
docker exec -it c57389dc94f5 sh
```

From the shell prompt, if I execute

```
more   /etc/alpine-release
```

I get `3.14.2`.

If I execute

```
more /proc/version
```

I get

```
Linux version 5.4.0-84-generic (buildd@lgw01-amd64-050) (gcc version 9.3.0 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04)) #94-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 26 20:27:37 UTC 2021
```

Why am I getting Ubuntu when the image uses Alpine?

Comment: Docker containers use the host kernel, and that's the data `uname` returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/cat/proc` give you the version of the OS which hosts the docker container, and not the docker image version. Remember that docker is not a virtual machine, but a bunch of isolated processes, named **container**, running on top of the hosting OS (and so, by its own kernel).

I guess that you are using docker on **Ubuntu**. Is it right?

Please refer to [official docker containers architecture](https://www.docker.com/resources/what-container).

Comment: You are right. I am using Ubuntu. But once I am 'inside' a container, why is it getting the host info?

Comment: As I explained, the docker executes container by the host kernel. I suggest you to go deeper into the docker architecture https://www.docker.com/resources/what-container .